# In LibreOffice, how to do a numbered and subnumbered list

Tags: indentation, libreoffice, numbered-list

This is ridicilous that LibreOffice wouldn't have this, I need simply this:

1. a
   1.1. a - first subsection
   1.2. a - second s.
2. something else
   2.1. asdv
   2.2.abgt
   2.3.arv
   2.4.ar

How do I do that automatically? As in - that libre office indents it automatically, and numerates it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to switch on the automatic, see [Creating Numbered or Bulleted Lists as You Type](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/swriter/guide/auto_numbering.html).

Additionally you can change the paragraph's formatting with [Bullets and Numbering](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/01/06050000.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=UNIX).